# APT - Knowing which package caused automatic installation of another package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Does apt support queries for package that caused installation of another package?

On listing a package using `apt list packagex` - from the output we can know if this package was installed manually or automatically. Say, `packagex` was installed automatically.

Now, I want to find out which package caused installation of `packagex`. (just finding reverese dependencies using `apt-cache showpkg packagex` might not be sufficient as there could be more than one package that depends on `packagex` )

Answer (score 3):

If you have `aptitude` installed then...

`aptitude why PACKAGENAME` gives you what you want.

If not you can install it with `sudo apt install aptitude`.

Sample output:

```
user:~$ aptitude why nvidia-driver-450
i   nvidia-driver-440 Depends nvidia-driver-450
user:~$ aptitude why nvidia-driver-440
Manually installed, current version 450.66-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, priority optional
No dependencies require to install nvidia-driver-440
```

Comment: `aptitude` isn't pre-installed. You can install it using APT though.